# How can I collect two-dimensional Array into a Map<String, Set<String>>?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

I have an array of arrays of two strings.

```
var array = new String[][]{
    {"a", "1"},
    {"a", "2"},
    {"b", "3"},
    ...
};
```

How can I collect the above array into a `Map<String, Set<String>>` whose key is the first element of each array and the value is a set of second elements of the array?

So that I get following map?

```
// Map<String, Set<String>>
<"a", ["1, "2"]>,
<"b", ["3"]>,
...
```

So far, I found I can classify the first element of each array like this.

```java
Arrays.stream(array).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        a -> ((String[])a)[0],
        // how can I collect the downstream?
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `Collectors.mapping` (also you don't need to specify `String[]` inside)

```
var array = new String[][]{{"a", "1"}, {"a", "2"}, {"b", "3"},};

Map<String, Set<String>> res = Arrays.stream(array).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        a -> a[0],
        Collectors.mapping(a -> a[1], Collectors.toSet())
));

System.out.println(res); // {a=[1, 2], b=[3]}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Collectors.mapping()` with a `toSet()` downstream:

```
Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[0],
    Collectors.mapping(v -> v[1], Collectors.toSet()))
```

Which produces `{a=[1, 2], b=[3]}`. That first maps stream elements to the array's second element, then collects those as a set mapped to the group key.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Collectors.groupingBy` in conjuction with `Collectors.mapping()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var array = new String[][]{
        {"a", "1"},
        {"a", "2"},
        {"b", "3"}
    };

    Map<String, Set<String>> result =
        Stream.of(array)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(arr -> arr[0],
                Collectors.mapping(arr -> arr[1],
                    Collectors.toSet())));

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Another way of doing this is to utilize `Collector.of()`:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> result =
    Stream.of(array)
        .collect(Collector.of(
            HashMap::new,
            (Map<String, Set<String>> map, String[] arr) ->
                map.computeIfAbsent(arr[0], k -> new HashSet<>()).add(arr[1]),
            (Map<String, Set<String>> left, Map<String, Set<String>> right) ->
                { left.putAll(right); return left; }));
```

**Output**

```
{a=[1, 2], b=[3]}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can simply do this by using for-each loop**

```
   Map<String, Set<String>> map=new HashMap<>();
   for(String []arr : array){
     Set<String> set = map.getOrDefault(arr[0], new HashSet<>());
     set.add(arr[1]);
     map.put(arr[0],set);
   }
   System.out.println(map);
```

**Output :**

`{a=[1, 2], b=[3]}`

Comment: `Set<String> set = map.getOrDefault(arr[0], new HashSet<>());` and remove the if/else

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Collectors.groupingBy`, you could use `Collectors.toMap`.

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[][] array = new String[][]{{"a", "1"}, {"a", "2"}, {"b", "3"}};
    Map<String, Set<String>> map = Arrays.stream(array).collect(Collectors.toMap(
            arr -> arr[0],
            arr -> new HashSet<>(Collections.singleton(arr[1])),
            (l, r) -> {
              l.addAll(r);
              return l;
            }));
    System.out.println(map);
  }
}
```

First parameter is `keyMapper`, second is `valueMapper`, third - `mergeFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your array and for every character you can check if this key is saved before in your map, if yes just push the corresponding character to the list of that repeated key

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).